# When I'm plotting bubble chart in plotly I'm getting an error

Tags: python, plotly-python, bubble-chart

I'm plotting bubble graph in plotly. My code is as below.

```
fig = px.scatter(data, x="gdp_per_capita", y="extreme_poverty",
             size="total_cases", color="continent",
                 hover_name="location")
fig.show()
```

I'm getting this error

> ```
>     Invalid element(s) received for the 'size' property of scattergl.marker
>     Invalid elements include: [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
>
> The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
>   - An int or float in the interval [0, inf]
>   - A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above
> ```

I've already used

> error_bad_lines=False

while importing the data.

Is there any way to resolve this error?
Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that the data you want to adapt to the size is numeric. If there is more NA, try replacing it with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have nan values in the dataframe. You need remove those values.

Either you can drop rows that contains nan in the column 'total_cases'

```
data = data.dropna(subset=['total_cases'])
```

Or you can fill NA with 0

```
data['total_cases'] = data.fillna(0)
```